# Mvc, Register area on the fly without using AreaRegistration

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, asp.net-mvc-areas

I try create a framework that work with multiple MVC project. I want to add each project as an area.
I can't use `AreaRegistration` in each project so I try simulate area in my code like this :

```
foreach (var module in InstalledModules)
{
    routeCollection.MapRoute(
        name: "Default_" + module.AreaName,
        url: module.AreaName + "/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
        namespaces: new[] { module.Namespace }
    );
}
```

The `InstalledModules` is a list of all modules that contain area name like `Module1` and root namespace of module assembly like `MvcProject.Module1`. The above code `MapRoute` all installed modules but it isn't work. For all request first registered rout hit and MVC try find controller in wrong assembly (location).

Is there any way to register project assemblies as area on the fly?

Or

**How I can customize the find matching route method?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you specified `Controllers` in namespace? your `InstalledModules` list must be like this :

```
var InstalledModules = new List<InstalledModule>
{
    new InstalledModule() { AreaName = "Main", Namespace ="MainWeb.Controllers"},
    new InstalledModule() { AreaName = "Web1", Namespace = "WebApplication1.Controllers"},
    new InstalledModule() { AreaName = "Web2", Namespace = "WebApplication2.Controllers"},
};
```

Comment: I tried with above code, it routes to /Main/Home, /Web1/Home, /Web2/Home normally.   
The problem is controllers always load views of /Main (MainWeb is startup project).   
I move views from Web1/Views, Web2/Views to MainWeb/Views then it works.

Comment: Yes you right. I found my problem. Route collection always contains a default route. When I remove this every this work fine. thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

I found my problem. Route collection always contains a default route. When I remove this every this work fine.